# Styling a q-popup-edit

Tags: css, vue.js, quasar

While working with Quasar in Vue, I'm using a q-popup-edit to get input from the user. I've tried Googling this, and read through the documentation, but I can't see how to set the style of a q-popup-edit object. We have access to the content-style for the popup when it's open, but the only thing we can set on the object itself is the height and width. Is there any way to set colors, font size, anything like that?

Here's my current code, in case it helps:

```
<q-popup-edit v-model="newName" auto-save v-slot="scope" style="font-min-size: large">
    <q-input v-model="newName" dense autofocus counter @keyup.enter="saveName" />
</ q-popup-edit>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply height and width in the parent element and it will work.

```
<div class="cursor-pointer" style="height:120px;width:120px">
      {{ label }}
      <q-popup-edit v-model="label" auto-save v-slot="scope">
        <q-input v-model="scope.value" dense autofocus counter @keyup.enter="scope.set"></q-input>
      </q-popup-edit>
    </div>
```

https://codepen.io/Pratik__007/pen/bGLjjVY